# Intercept Webview Request Xaml

Tags: windows, xaml, webview, win-universal-app

I need to insert a custom user agent and auth token into all the request's made from webview. Is it possible to intercept the HttpRequests made from the webview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In UWP, we should be able to use [`WebView.NavigateWithHttpRequestMessage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.navigatewithhttprequestmessage.aspx) method to navigate the WebView to a URI with a POST request and HTTP headers.

There is a [`NavigationStarting`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.navigationstarting.aspx) event in WebView, it occurs before the WebView navigates to new content. So we should able to set the [`WebViewNavigationStartingEventArgs.Cancel`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webviewnavigationstartingeventargs.cancel.aspx) property to `true` to cancel the navigation.

For example:

```cs
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    NavigateWithHeader(new Uri("http://www.whoishostingthis.com/tools/user-agent/"));
}

private void NavigateWithHeader(Uri uri)
{
    var requestMsg = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, uri);
    string ua = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko";
    requestMsg.Headers.Add("User-Agent", ua);
    MyWebView.NavigateWithHttpRequestMessage(requestMsg);
    MyWebView.NavigationStarting += Wb_NavigationStarting;
}

private void Wb_NavigationStarting(WebView sender, WebViewNavigationStartingEventArgs args)
{
    MyWebView.NavigationStarting -= Wb_NavigationStarting;
    args.Cancel = true;
    NavigateWithHeader(args.Uri);
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to intercept the request made from Javascript also. I want to load the below mentioned content in webview. The javascript will generate the Detailed page but the problem is for the generated html content, protocol is not specified(http or https) in the src for images and js files. I want to add this manually for the page to work

Comment: "<div id='flix-minisite'></div><div id='flix-inpage'></div><script type = 'text/javascript' src = 'http://media.flixfacts.com/js/loader.js'  data-flix-distributor='12612' data-flix-language='id' data-flix-brand='Samsung' data-flix-mpn='UA55JU6600KPXD' data-flix-ean='' data-flix-sku='' data-flix-button='flix-minisite' data-flix-inpage='flix-inpage' data-flix-button-image='' data-flix-fallback-language='e2' data-flix-price='' async></script>"